# Looping over data frame to cap and sum another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use entries from `df1` to limit amounts in `df2`, then add them up based on their type and summarize in `df3`.  I'm not sure how to get it, the for loop using iterrows would be my best guess but it's not complete.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Caps':['25','50','100']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Amounts':['45','25','65','35','85','105','80'], \
                    'Type':   ['a' ,'b' ,'b' ,'c' ,'a' , 'b' ,'d' ]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':   ['a' ,'b' ,'c' ,'d']})

df1['Caps'] = df1['Caps'].astype(float)
df2['Amounts'] = df2['Amounts'].astype(float)

for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df3.iterrows():
        df3[str(row1['Caps']+'limit')] = df2['Amounts'].where(
            df2['Type'] == row2['Type']).where(
            df2['Amounts']<= row1['Caps'], row1['Caps']).sum()


# My ideal output would be this:

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['a','b','c','d'],
                    'Total':['130','195','35','80'],
                    '25limit':['50','75','25','25'],
                    '50limit':['95','125','35','50'],
                    '100limit':['130','190','35','80'],
                    })
```

**Output:**

```
>>> df3

  Type Total 25limit 50limit 100limit
0    a   130      50      95      130
1    b   195      75     125      190
2    c    35      25      35       35
3    d    80      25      50       80
```

Comment: How you calculate `25limit` and `100limit` for `a` ?

Comment: I look for all the values in df2 that correspond to 'a', mainly 45 and 85, then I limit them to 25 and 100 correspondingly, and add them up.  So 25+25=50 for the 25limit, and 45+85=130 for the 100limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use numpy for compare all values `Amounts` with `Caps` by broadcasting to 2d array `a`, then create `DataFrame` by constructor with `sum` per columns, transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html).

For aggregated column use [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) for first column with [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
df1['Caps'] = df1['Caps'].astype(int)
df2['Amounts'] = df2['Amounts'].astype(int)

am = df2['Amounts'].to_numpy()
ca = df1['Caps'].to_numpy()
#pandas below 0.24
#am = df2['Amounts'].values
#ca = df1['Caps'].values
a  = np.where(am <= ca[:, None], am[None, :], ca[:, None])

df1 = (pd.DataFrame(a,columns=df2['Type'],index=df1['Caps'])
         .sum(axis=1, level=0).T.add_suffix('limit'))
df1.insert(0, 'Total', df2.groupby('Type')['Amounts'].sum())
df1 = df1.reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
  Type  Total  25limit  50limit  100limit
0    a    130       50       95       130
1    b    195       75      125       190
2    c     35       25       35        35
3    d     80       25       50        80
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution without numpy, however it is two times slower than @jezrael's solution, 10.5ms vs. 5.07ms.

```
limcols= df1.Caps.to_list()
df2=df2.reindex(columns=["Amounts","Type"]+limcols)

df2[limcols]= df2[limcols].transform( \
                  lambda sc: np.where(df2.Amounts.le(sc.name),df2.Amounts,sc.name))

# Summations:
g=df2.groupby("Type")
df3= g[limcols].sum()
df3.insert(0,"Total", g.Amounts.sum())

# Renaming columns:
c_dic={ lim:f"{lim:.0f}limit" for lim in limcols}
df3= df3.rename(columns=c_dic).reset_index()

# Cleanup:
#df2=df2.drop(columns=limcols)
```